# how to select * from XML where id=1?

Tags: sql-server-2008, xml

```
declare @xml xml,
declare @num int
set @num = 1
set @xml = '
<row>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <name>reza</name>
</row>
<row>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <name>Masoud</name>
</row>
'
```

**how to select ID = @num ??**

Comment: Doesn't replacing `1` with `@num` in marc_s's answer solve your problem?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask something different then unaccept valid answers to your previous question. `select @xml.query('*[Id/text()=sql:variable("@num")]');` should work I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [XPath filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
select @xml.query('*[Id/text()="1"]');
```

will show: `<row><Id>1</Id><name>reza</name></row>`. `'/row[Id/text()="1"]'` would also work for your example, as well as `'/row[Id="1"]'` or even `'/row[Id=1]'`.

Comment: @SQLKiwi: I think we should make a competition rule that one need to *shorten* the expression, not expanding it ;)

Comment: @SQLKiwi: yes, the `()[1]` forces a singleton indeed (as we well know from what `.value()` is keep forcing us to do...)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select 
    XRows.query('.')
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/row') AS XTbl(XRows)
WHERE
    XRows.value('(Id)[1]', 'int') = 1
```

This will return the entire `<row>` XML element as XML